# When click actionbutton to refresh plot there is a table that is not be refreshed

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

I created a shinyapp and there are three vital buttons.

The three buttons works well

And the click3 can output a plot and a table togather.

Now I met a problem that plot1, plot2 and plot3(plot3 and the heatmap output togather) can refresh each other ideally.But it works doesn't look like that.

The output table always keep stay there no matter click1 or click2 clicked.

I tried modifying my code but it didn't work.

**I hope somebody could give me some advice that the table will diappear with the heatmpa no matter which button clicked.**

My reproducible code and data here:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
##  load("04.21_3.RData")

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))


############
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput(
      "selectGeneSymbol", 
      "Select:", 
      choices = NULL,
      multiple =F,
      width = 400,
      selected = NULL,
      options = list(placeholder = 'e.g. gene here',create = F)
    ),
    actionButton("plot1", "click1"),
    actionButton("plot2", "click2"),
    actionButton("dataTable", "click3")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("all"),
#    plotOutput("myPlot"),
    tableOutput("myTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectGeneSymbol", choices = colnames(mean_data[,-1]), server = TRUE)
  
  global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL,
                           p1 = NULL,
                           p2 = NULL)
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1,{ 
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })

  output$all <- renderUI({                      ##
    global$out
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot1")
  })
  ##
  observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot2")
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$dataTable, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot")
  })
  ####
  myPlot = reactiveVal()
  myData = reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$dataTable, {
    data_cor<-mean_data[,-1]
    tm <- corr.test(data_cor[,input$selectGeneSymbol,drop=FALSE],
                    y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                    alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
    res <-setNames(as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, tm[c("r", "p")]))), c("Correlation", "P_value"))
    res<-res[-which(rownames(res)== input$selectGeneSymbol),]
    res<-data.frame(Gene=rownames(res),res)
    res
    ##############
    data_correlation=t(mean_data[, -1])
    data_subset=data_correlation[c(input$selectGeneSymbol, as.vector(head(res$Gene, 10))), ]
    myPlot(
        pheatmap(log2(data_subset+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =12,
                 cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, gaps_row = 1)
    )
    myData(res)
  })
  
  output$myPlot = renderPlot({
    myPlot()
  })
  
  output$myTable = renderTable({
    myData()
  })
  
  ####
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1,
                      {
                        ggplot(data =plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]])) +
                          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                          theme(legend.position = "none") +
                          labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "666666")                      })
  
  p2 <- eventReactive(input$plot2,
                      {
                        ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]], fill=Name)) +
                          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                          theme(legend.position = "none") +
                          labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "777777")                      })                    
                      
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    p1()})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    p2()})
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot1")
    myData(NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot2")
    myData(NULL)
  })
```

Comment: Huh, thanks,sir. I have no idea about my question but your message give me the direction.